# Should i make admin panel in different hosting?

Tags: architecture, admin

recently i joined new company. In there, my PM insists to have admin page at different instance in AWS.
Because of that, our developer should update both side. For example, If payment class is changed, we should update for admin side and user-view-side as PM wants the application to be installed in different instance.

I asked him why we do it and he said that in finance company it is very common to do. When the site is hacked, it can minimize damage. But we are a new start up company so this process slow development a lot and i do not find any point of doing this. When front page is hacked somehow, the hacker may access to our database.

Is it really common to have admin page at different hosting or instance in AWS?

Comment: SO isn't designed to be used to settle disagreements or arguments at your office. This should be an internal discussion with your development and project management teams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It does not matter whether your project is financial or not.
Your code serves two different audience groups and do different things.
If you make mistake in your code or configuration then mistake in one app will affect both user groups (both apps) and this is not good.**

Lets suppose that your two independent applications are deployed to the shared hosting.
You pay less money for such hosting compared to VPS or dedicated server.
While you get computing resources for cheap you also not getting any guarantee that your code will work in a predicatble manner.
So first application could interfere with operation of second application.
And multiple applications which you are even not aware of will work alongside your apps while sharing valuble resources: RAM, CPU, Bandwidth, HDD storage etc.

Such resources sharing can play well at start and keep infrastructure costs low but you never know when you trip the wire.

So if you look at your app this way you will see that PM's preferences(suggestion) make sense.

It is good idea to design your app in a such way that it could scale horizontaly.
I assume you are ok with idea that your app should work at several servers at once to serve as many client as possible.
When there are to many client requests then you just start extra instance and you are ok.
Right?

Your PM is just suggesting you to start with 2 instances and it should not bother you.

He is worried about stability but not about architecture design.

So here are 2 extreme options:

- You can achieve stability and scalability without splitting your monolithic app into two different apps - just deploy this app to different instances and let users use the part they need (i.e. let staff use backend and let visitors use frontend).
- You can follow microservices approach and split your app into separate components. You can move all payment logic into third service and use it in front-end and backend via thin client API interface (which could be actually automatically re-generated when you make the change to the interface)